# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor after ransonware attack

Tags: python

I was usinng python 3.7 to   write a  project in Django but my computer was attacked by the .horon malware.I managed to remove the malware but since that I have not been able to run the djang commands in  my projects.For exmaple when I type "python manage.py runserver ",it throws the following error : OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

I have unistalled,repaired and reinstalled pythonbut the error still persists

Comment: Here is the error message  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: Create a new fresh virtual environment for your project. (Even if you did not have one in the first place.)

Comment: The errors persists even when  I try creating a new  virtual environment

Comment: Then inspect your project files for any damage and do a full filesystem check.

Comment: I did sytem check,but it seems not to work yet